# Tail changing files

Tags: linux, text-processing, tail

I'm trying to append file by watching data that constantly adding every second and pipe data to new files that will process it later. using

```
tail -f 'data file' >> 'destination file'
```

But some how some line is duplicate so I do this.

```
tail -f 'data file' | awk '!seen[$0]++' | >> 'destination file'
```

This seem fine , But the line would be split some time so I guess I need to buffer the whole line to achieve this. But is this a good way to do this or should I do it another way ?

```
tail -f 'data file' | grep --line-buffered -E '^.*$' | awk '!seen[$0++]'
```

Full data example

```
[9/10/17 14:21:09] Data=[xxx|yyy|zzz]
```

Split example

```
[9/1
[9/10/17 14:21:09] Data=[xx
```

something like this. This happen after I pipe data from `tail` to `awk`.
So I move `grep` to end of command and it's work. But data will hold in buffer instead if it was too small.

```
tail -f 'data file' | awk '!seen[$0++]' | grep --line-buffered -E '^.*$'
```

Thanks for advice and answer !

Comment: Full msg [9/10/17 14:21:09] Data=[xxx|yyy|zzz]
Split [9/1    ,  [9/10/17 14:21:09] Data=[xx
something like this. This happen after I pipe data from tail to awk.
    tail -f 'data file' | awk '!seen[$0++]' | grep --line-buffered -E '^.*$' 
I move grep to end of command and it's work , thanks.

Comment: Are you actually seeing split lines in your `destination file`? `tail -f` is not line buffered, but the output from `awk` should be. And neither will be adding extra newlines to the data.

Comment: It isn't new line. The line isn't complete when the other process read from destination file. Hence broke the other process.

Comment: Oh, so the program that reads from `destination file` is broken, and you need to workaround that? I see.

Comment: @Nrto What is that other process that reads from the destination file?  That process appears to be the problem.

Comment: @John1024 That process is nodejs ( javascript ) that will output data to websocket and nats. I think I need to fix on that process then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> But some how some line is duplicate

If the duplicates are adjacent lines you can try `uniq`:

```
$ tail -f <file> | uniq
```

In a quick test this worked as expected, waiting for a complete line before writing the output.

If the duplicate lines are scattered over the file, adding `uniq` to the pipe between `tail` and `awk` might still help.